# How to use NSPredicate to return true?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

Here is my code:

```
let newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "true == %@")        
let y = newPredicate.evaluate(with: true)

print(y)
```

It always returns `false`.

How to use `NSPredicate` to return `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%@` placeholder is for arguments passed to the `NSPredicate(format:)` call, like this:

```
let newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "true == %@", true)
```

If you want to use the object passed to `evaluate(with:)`, use `self`:

```
let newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "true == self")
let y = newPredicate.evaluate(with: true)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a default or fallback predicate that always evaluate to true:

`NSPredicate.init(value: true)`